# Error 404 in ckan source operator - wirecloud

Tags: ckan, fiware-wirecloud

I try to set up the ckan source operator with the available dataset (in csv format) giving the dataset url, id and either leaving blank the credentials of idm authorization or writing my client id. An error "404 - Not Found" occurs.
Any tip?

Comment: Are you using a public CKAN instance? If so, please add the info into your question so we are able to reproduce your problem. In any case, would be great to have more information, e.g. the CKAN version, the CKAN source operator version, ...

Comment: Hi. I am using the CKAN instance in Fi-Lab . CKAN Source operator Version 0.4.3 .

Comment: Perhaps i have something misunderstood. I use the idm credentials that in the account of fiware-lab i have , am i right or should i install the idm in a topical server? Also, the course in "http://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=53#section-3" is broken longer than two weeks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It finally works with the upgrade of CKAN Source Operator with the version 0.4.5 launched by ConWet !!!